# How to display order items in one row

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve unlimited number of products joined in order row. for example user have selected 10 items in single order, i want to display each product_id and product_slug in single row with order_id. delivery address also added in last column.

My Table is like this

```
## Orders Table ##

order_id | customerId | order_date   | status  | verification_code
 1          7           2014-04-04   
 2          10          2014-04-04
```

---

```
## Order Items Table ##

item_id | orderId | productId   | qty  | status
 1          1          21          2   
 2          1          22          1
 3          2          21          3
 4          2          23          1
```

### Products Table

```
product_id | user_id | product_slug  

 1           11         new-t-shirt    
 2           12         denim-jeans    
 3           13         t-shirt        
 4           14         jacket
```

I want to display result like this

```
Order_ID | Product_ID1 | Product_slug1 | Product_ID2 | Product_slug2
_____________________________________________________________________
 1          21            T-shirt          22            Jeans
 2          21            T-Shirt          23            Denim-Jeans
```

Comment: dude.. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: in addition what if one order contains purchase of 50 items there is no such end and even with doing some case -when within the query it becomes a recursive one !!

Answer (score 0):

You can not dynamically add columns depending on the number of joined rows since every order might have a different number of colums but what you can do is list them all in a row anyway like that:

```
SELECT orders.order_id, GROUP_CONCAT(products.product_id SEPERATOR ','), GROUP_CONCAT(products.product_slug SEPERATOR ',')
FROM orders
JOIN items
ON orders.order_id = items.order_id
JOIN products.product_id = items.product_id
GROUP BY orders.order_id
```

This creates commar-seperated lists in every row. From there you can go through your list of product_ids and product_slugs to do whatever you want to do with them.

For informations about GROUP_CONCAT see here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat